# Can't get a crawler playing solo? 

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Up until recently I used to be able to get a crawler by using explosives and gain some time to rebuild barricades and get weapons in between rounds. Now I can't seem to get ANY crawlers in Solo and I have tried many times with grenades, rocket launchers, etc. into large groups of enemies on levels as high as round 80 with no crawlers produced. However, I can play multi-player and get crawlers fine. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 thats really odd and all i can imagine is that its some sort of bug, have you tried resetting ur console and trying again? Has it been patched so that crawlers no longer appear solo? (you could also just keep a nova gas zombie alive as they are rather slow)

Comment: No I haven't tried resetting the console, might be worth trying. That is what I was wondering if there was a patch that stopped crawlers from happening. And yep, thats what i'm forced to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a not-too-common but known issue.  Crawlers are blocked when the Graphic Content settings of the game are set too low.  With graphic content set low, there is no red blood allowed, and no "missing-limbs" enemies, which would explain the no-crawler issue.

To fix it, start the game, then go to **Settings** > **Game** > **Graphic Content** and change it from "Reduced" to "**Unrestricted**".

Comment: That's a great thought, but I already have it on unrestricted.

Comment: However, that may fix some peoples problems in the future if this really is a fix. So I will accept it for now.

Comment: @Nick if it's not that, then it's gotta be a glitch.  Try moving your save game to another drive (so that black ops starts fresh) and see if it still happens.